# Unicode Comparing in PHP/MySQL

Tags: mysql, unicode

The name Accîdent seems to be different than AccÎdent when I do a database query to update the column. Yet [Accîdent](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/sargeras/acc%C3%AEdent/advanced) and [AccÎdent](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/sargeras/acc%C3%8Edent%20/advanced) point to the same place...

In MySQL Accîdent  = AccÃ®dent when inserted.
Also, AccÎdent = AccÃŽdent.

Do you know why this is?

Comment: What is the collation of your database and/or table? (You can find this out by visiting your database/table in phpMyAdmin.)

Comment: You seem to have the in-database encoding messed up - when inserted, the data should look the same as before. Are your tables and the relevant columns utf8? It seems as if you created them as latin1, or some other encoding - check also the connection encoding.

Comment: the only difference I see in these links is a trailing space in the second one

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear with my questions... First I was wondering if it's possible to make a link between the two spellings... For some reason when a player adds their character to the database it will check the db and if it does not exist it will add a new character. So in this situation, the same character is added twice, when it's essentially the same character.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, look at the i's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, MySQL assumes the client uses the `latin1` character set. If you're using UTF-8 in your PHP scripts, then this assumption is false. You need to specify to MySQL that you're using UTF-8 by issuing this SQL statement just after the database connection is opened:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Then the data inserted by the following SQL statements will use the correct character set. This means that you need to re-insert your data or follow the [MySQL conversion procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-conversion.html) (see the last paragraphs).

It is recommended that your tables are configured to store data in UTF-8, too, to avoid unnecessary read/write character set conversions. That's not required, though.

More information is available in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset.html). Specifically, [Connection Character Sets and Collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-connection.html).

Comment: ...note that the tables need to be UTF-8, too, otherwise operations with non-ASCII characters will fail (or worse, be silently changed to gibberish)

Comment: The tables don't need to be UTF-8 since MySQL handles the charset conversions automatically behind your back. However, the charset conversions are obviously unnecessary, and will cause problems with UTF-8 characters which are not representable in the table charset.

Comment: They don't *need* to be UTF-8, true - but then exactly the OP's problem will appear ("it appears normally in PHP, but it's all weird when I check the database directly").

Comment: They will look fine in the database, since MySQL will convert them to the "screen" encoding before display.

Answer (score 0):

- First, you seem to be storing UTF-8 data in a table of different encoding. MySQL will try and cope, but the side effect is as you see - data in the database will look "weird". When creating a table, you need to specify the character encoding - preferably UTF-8. For existing tables, you'll need to convert the data.
- Second, the tables have a "collation" beside encoding. Encoding determines how the characters map to bytes, collation determines sorting and comparison. There are language-specific collations, but `utf8_general_ci` should be the one you're looking for (`ci` stands for "case insensitive") - then your two string would match.

Comment: The issue lies with the connection charset (MySQL assumes the PHP scripts is talking in `latin1` instead of `utf8`), not the table charset. See my own answer.

Comment: @e-t172: That is possible. Pending more information from the OP, I'm cautious to say what the issue *definitely* is.